# Why can I not ssh into RHEL 8.2 when sshd is running and port 22 shows it's open?

Tags: ssh, redhat-enterprise-linux, sshd

I installed RHEL 8.2 with a free developer license (bare hardware), it looks like sshd is installed, running by default with port 22 already open, I did not have to do anything to install sshd or open the port.

---

```
[root@<hostname> etc]# systemctl status sshd
● sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-08-17 13:35:12 MDT; 1h 7min ago
   ...
```

but on Windows 10 Pro (with cygwin ssh client installed),

```
ssh <user>@<ip-address>
```

I get this error

```
ssh: connect to host <ip-address> port 22: Permission denied
```

On the RHEL 8.2 installation, in a bash terminal, I can successfully ssh locally: `ssh <user>@<ip-address>` and it works OK.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the problem is on the client (Cygwin) side; but just to be sure, try `telnet ip-address 22` and see if you get a connection or a "Connect failed" / "Connection refused" message. If the connection succeeds, then you've ruled out things like `iptables` and `selinux` policy filtering on the server side. An alternative is to run `tcpdump` on the server while using ssh to connect, which can confirm that you get packets in both directions on port 22.

Assuming the server side is OK, try another ssh client, such as PuTTY. If this works, you may have a problem with your Cygwin installation.